# Changing manual pivot to dynamic pivot getting aggregate function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a stored procedure for pivoting manually

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[performancepivot] (
    @startdate datetime, 
    @enddate datetime
) as begin

    set nocount on
    declare @date1 nvarchar(100)=convert(varchar, @startdate+'00:00:00.000',120),
            @date2 nvarchar(100)= convert(varchar, @enddate+'23:59:59.000',120);

    with cte as 
          dbo.testfunctionstacknew(convert(decimal(10,1),avg(convert(numeric(18,2), datediff(ss, t.Paydate, t.DelDate))))) as Average
        from Transaction_tbl as t
            left join VType_tbl as v on t.vtid = v.vtid
            left join Location_tbl as l on t.Locid = l.Locid
        where t.Locid in (select t1.Locid from Transaction_tbl as t1)
          and t.dtime between @date1 and @date2
          and t.Status = 5
        group by v.Vtype, l.LocName, l.Locid)

    select c.LocName, 
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Normal' then Average end) as Normal,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Vip' then Average end) as Vip,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'VVip'   then Average end) as VVip,   
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Pass' then Average end) as Pass,
        max(case when c.Vtype = 'Staff' then Average end) as Staff  
    from cte as c group by c.LocName order by c.LocName
end
```

while executing this i am getting exact out put..i dont want pivot manually..so i try to write stored procedure 'pivot Dynamically'..
i try to write stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[ParkingSummary1]
     @startdate nvarchar(100), @enddate nvarchar(100) as
    begin 
      declare @date1 nvarchar(100) = convert(varchar, @startdate+' 00:00:00.000', 120)
      declare @date2 nvarchar(100) = convert(varchar, @enddate+' 23:59:59.000', 120)
      DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
      select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype) from VType_tbl
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')
      set @query = 'SELECT LocName, ' + @cols + '(  
      select l.LocName,v.Vtype,[dbo].[testfunctionstacknew](
      CONVERT(decimal(10,1), AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),
      DATEDIFF(SS,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ) ))) as Average  
     from (select l.LocName,Vtype from   Transaction_tbl t join
      VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid join dbo.Location_tbl l on 
      t.locid=l.Locid  where dtime between '''+ @date1 +''' and '''+ @date2 +'''  
      and Status = 5) d  pivot  ( count(Vtype) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')) p '
      print @query
     exec sp_executesql @query;
      end
```

but while executing this stored procedure i am getting error:Column 'Location_tbl.LocName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
 what is wrong with my second stored procedure..if any one know please help me to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to execute the command in @query. "print @query" only outputs the command itself. Useful for debugging, so just comment that line out..

insert this under the print command:

```
exec sp_executesql @query;
```

more on sp_executesql here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170(v=sql.105).aspx

EDIT:

The query you generated contains errors. Also it is unnecessary to convert datetimes to varchars to accomplish what you want. This here should fix both (beware, blind coded, @query is only made syntactically correct)

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ParkingSummary1] (
     @startdate datetime
     , @enddate datetime )
     as
    begin
      DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
      declare @params nvarchar(50) = '@date1 datetime, @date2 datetime';
      declare @date1 datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @startdate), 0);
      declare @date2 datetime = dateadd(day, datediff(day, 0, @enddate) + 1, 0);

      select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype) from VType_tbl
      FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)')  ,1,1,'')

      set @query = 'SELECT LocName, ' + @cols + '
      from 
      (
        select l.LocName, Vtype, [dbo].[testfunctionstacknew](
            CONVERT(decimal(10,1), AVG( CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,2),
            DATEDIFF(SS,t.Paydate,t.DelDate) ) ))) as Average 
        from Transaction_tbl t 
        join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid 
        join dbo.Location_tbl l on t.locid=l.Locid 
        where dtime >= @date1 and dtime < @date2
        and Status = 5
        group by l.LocName, VType
       ) d 
       pivot ( max(Average) for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')) p '
    print @query;
    --pass date1 and date2 as datetime parameters, not varchars.
    exec sp_executesql @query, @params, @date1, @date2
end
```

remember to print the variables to debug. Also check the sp_executesql website for an explanation of the @query,@params,@date1,@date2 syntax.

Comment: now am getting error:Column 'Location_tbl.LocName' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: while executing your new stroed procedure getting two error:The multi-part identifier "t.Paydate" could not be bound. and The multi-part identifier "t.DelDate" could not be bound.

Comment: actually i want to convert my first stored procedure to dynamically pivot stored procedure

Comment: OK, I updated the proc. Would be better to use avg in the pivot, but you need to run a convert and testfunctionstacknew on the results, so that's why the group+avg occurs in the inner query. It -is- possible to do pivot ( avg (somecol) .. but that would mean you have to run testfunctionstacknew on every result column and that would mean a complete rewrite of the procedure.

Comment: yes perfect..i got exact out put..i shall be very thank full to you